# HTML Table does not use full screen

Tags: html, css, html-table

### Situation:

I'm writing an html page and I added a head and body.
In my body I have 3 columns, left, main and right.

For this question only the main is important. I wanted to make a table with text in the main column. I only added 3 lines of text so the table is not completely filled, but still I want the table to be the full height of the screen, just to improve the look. Then it will be a lager box instead of a little box in the middle of the screen.

**In my CSS file I have this:**

```
    html {height:100%; width: 100%;}

    body 
    {
      margin:0; 
      height:100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: blue;
    }   

    #table1
     {
       background-color: black;
       height: 100%;
       width: 70%;
       z-index: 1;
       padding:15px;
     }
```

For some reason the *height: 100%* does not work. Does someone has an explanation?

Comment: Do you have this somewhere in jsfiddle?

Comment: No i'm sorry.. It is the same as the code on my other question, the only problem is that I want my table to be 100% height.

Comment: If your table occupies 100%, how can the footer be below it then? Do you want the footer to overlap the table?

Comment: Hmm that is a good question.. I didn't thought about that.. What about 90% ? Is that Possible? Or is it possible to let the footer and table occupie 100% together?

Comment: put the table and the footer div inside a div. And, make that div 100% not the table itself.

Comment: Is that even possible? Doesn't the footer has to stay out of the wrap like it is now?

Comment: That's possible, just not preferable. If you open a gist/jsfiddle, I can make the changes.

Comment: Open a what..? I'm sorry I'm new here..

Comment: try putting your code here and share the link with me: http://jsbin.com/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/abamop/1/
Here you go, I saw another problem/question. If you still want to help me I would be very happy if I can ask you after this one. :)

Comment: This discussion is getting long and your reputation won't let us chat. I don't know how I should be helping you. Anyways, the page looks fine to me. what's the problem? You have a table + sticky footer.

Comment: If you opened the jsbin, you can see the page at the right corner, when it is smal the Home button covers up the table, how to fix that?

Comment: You don't need to fix that. That's just how jsbin is. See the full site if you want to assess your work accurately. Checkout bootstrap-responsive, if you want you page to work fine on small screens too.

Comment: The real page works the same as jsbin.. And what is bootstrap-responsive..? I'm feeling really noob right now..
I'm so sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/ I recommend you to play with this a little and dive into your project again. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make an element 100% height, you usually have to give the `body` and `html` 100% height as well.

Add

```
body, html { height: 100%; }
```

to your CSS.

You'll need to set the height of all elements in the hierarchy for this to work. Think of it as "100% of what? the element that is my parent." So what's that parent's height?

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/adohed/1/edit)

Comment: I did that, but still I have the same problem..? Is it possible?

Comment: Do 100% height to all elements in the hierarchy. See #bar in my demo

Comment: It still doesn't uses the whole screen? Maybe it is because I'm using an header and footer? Could that be the problem? I changed the question and added the CSS lines for my body and html, is that what you mean?

Comment: You'll have to post some HTML to make a complete example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I fixed it, I tried to understand what you were saying and I asked myself, What's the parent's height? And then I fixed it, so thank you very much! You helped me solve this :)

Comment: Can you help me with my other question too? Please? @sachleen

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to give your body a height of 100% too , cause your table is in your body, so when you tell the table to take 100% of the height, it's actually 100% of the body height , which is itself not 100%...

Answer (score 0):

You must set the CSS height property of the entire main column to 100%, here, you are only setting the table height to 100% of the main div, which is not 100% of the screen.